# Elasticsearch does not match a partial query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm currently trying to create an analyzer that will match a part of a query. The main use case is with this term "3D mammogram", for some reason using my autocomplete analyzer down below, produces no results. Upon removing the "operator" : "AND" option, elastic started to return results but still the results that are expected are with less score for some reason.

Here are the settings and the mappings for my index:

MAPPINGS:

```
{
    "index": {
        "properties": {
            "code": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "term": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "index_search"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SETTINGS:

```
{
  "index" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "provided_name" : "index",
        "creation_date" : ".......",
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "case_transition_filter" : {
              "split_on_numerics" : "true",
              "type" : "word_delimiter",
              "preserve_original" : "true",
              "stem_english_possessive" : "false"
            },
            "autocomplete_filter" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "max_gram" : "15"
            },
            "hyphen-filter" : {
              "pattern" : "-",
              "type" : "pattern_replace",
              "replacement" : " "
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "filter" : [ "case_transition_filter", "lowercase", "hyphen-filter", "autocomplete_filter" ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "keyword"
            },
            "index_search" : {
              "type" : "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : ".....g",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "..."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm using two different analyzers - the autocomplete one for indexing and a standard one for search.

From my backend I'm hitting the elastic index with these two match queries wrapped in a bool query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "term" : {
            "query" : "3d mammogram",
            "operator" : "AND",
            "analyzer" : "keyword",
            "fuzziness" : "1",
            "prefix_length" : 1,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 2.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "term" : {
            "query" : "3d mammogram",
            "operator" : "AND",
            "fuzziness" : "1",
            "prefix_length" : 1,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "minimum_should_match" : "1",
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Both of the queries like that produce no results but upon removing the "operator" : "AND" from the second query I'm starting to get good results but not the ones that I expect.
Here are the results from the second query:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 93,
    "max_score" : 20.951433,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index",
        "_type" : "index",
        "_id" : ".....",
        "_score" : 20.951433,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Routine mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 19.059473,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "....",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 18.515629,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Screening mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "search-term",
        "_id" : "....",
        "_score" : 18.515629,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "treatment procedures",
          "term" : "Diagnostic mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "....",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 18.515629,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Digital mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 18.480751,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Screening 3D mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 18.376223,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "t...",
          "term" : "Diagnostic 3D mammogram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 17.930023,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Mammography"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "...",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "....",
        "_score" : 17.287262,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Screening mammography"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "....",
        "_type" : "...",
        "_id" : "...",
        "_score" : 17.287262,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : null,
          "careNeedCode" : "...",
          "careNeedType" : "...",
          "term" : "Abnormal mammography"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see the results containing "3d mammogram" are way below than results that have only "mammogram" in them. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your index mapping and settings, the tokens generated for `"Screening 3D mammogram"` will be

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "sc",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scr",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scre",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scree",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screen",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screeni",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screenin",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening 3",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening 3d",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening 3d ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening 3d m",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening 3d ma",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "sc",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scr",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scre",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scree",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screen",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screeni",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screenin",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "screening",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "ma",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mam",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mamm",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mammo",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mammog",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mammogr",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mammogra",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "mammogram",
      "start_offset": 13,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

**There is no token generated for `3d`. This is because you have taken `"tokenizer" : "keyword"` for the `autocomplete` analyzer. You need to modify your index mapping and change the `tokenizer` from `keyword` to `standard`**

Modified index mapping will be

```
"analyzer" : {
            "autocomplete" : {
              "filter" : [ "case_transition_filter", "lowercase", "hyphen-filter", "autocomplete_filter" ],
              "type" : "custom",
              "tokenizer" : "standard"       // note this
            },
```

You need to reindex the data again with this new index mapping.

---

Adding a working example with index data,index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "case_transition_filter": {
          "split_on_numerics": "true",
          "type": "word_delimiter",
          "preserve_original": "true",
          "stem_english_possessive": "false"
        },
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "15"
        },
        "hyphen-filter": {
          "pattern": "-",
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "replacement": " "
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "filter": [
            "case_transition_filter",
            "lowercase",
            "hyphen-filter",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard"           // note this
        },
        "search_term_search": {
          "type": "standard" 
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 20
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "term": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "search_term_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*The tokens generated will include `"3d"` and `"mammogram"` both.*

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "term": "Screening mammogram"
}
{
  "term": "Diagnostic 3D mammogram"
}
{
  "term": "Mammography"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "term": {
        "query": "3D mammogram",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67607194",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.4572026,
        "_source": {
          "term": "Diagnostic 3D mammogram"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I applied the changes using a standard tokenizer but still I get no results when I search for "3d mammogram" for some reason. When I search for "mammogram" I get results but for some reason elastic doesn't like the 3D. 

This is the query that my index does not like: 
GET /search-term-v2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "term": {
        "query": "3d mammogram",
        "operator": "and", 
        "analyzer": "autocomplete_standard_custom"
      }
    }
  }
}


The analyzer I use is the same as the autocomplete but with a standard tokenizer.

Comment: @Aethernite it's not like *elastic doesn't like the 3D* :D !! Can you please share your updated index mapping? Have you used the same index mapping as given in the above answer, because I tested it locally and it is working fine

Comment: @Aethernite is the search result shown in my answer, similar to what you expect to get ?

Comment: To test it I follow these steps:
- close the index
- put a new analyzer it with the new changes
- call the _analyze endpoint with the text I want "3d mammogram" with an "operator" : "and" and the new analyzer that has standard tokenizer. 

The query "3d mammogram" produces no results but the query "mammogram" produces the results I expect.

And yes your search result is what I expect. The terms that have "3D" in them to be appearing first.

Comment: @Aethernite when calling `_analyze` endpoint for `"3d mammogram"` what do you get ? Are the tokens for `3d` and `mammogram` present?

Comment: @Aethernite can you please share the output of Analyze API for `"3d mammogram"` and `autocomplete` analyzer. This will help me to understand what tokens are getting indexed in your index  `GET /_analyze     {
  "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
  "text" : "Screening 3D mammogram"
}`

Comment: Here is a pastebin with all the queries and the results from them plus the _analyze for the new analyzer: https://pastebin.com/04N6Hudy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232639/discussion-between-escoder-and-aethernite).